# `cleartool lsco -r -cvi -me` is extremely slow compared to `cleartool lsco -graphical`. Is it possible to improve it's performance?

Tags: windows, clearcase

I'd like to be able to utilize lsco on the command line for better integration with Emacs, but it runs prohibitively slowly!

Usually, GUIs are slower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the technote "[Recursively checkout and checkin elements](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122520)":

> It is recommended that if performance is degraded due to this recursive operation that either the operation be changed (say to checkout/checkin in smaller chunks) or to stop the operation all together.

In other words, the recursive nature of lsco (and associated commands) doesn't scale well.
As opposed to the GUI, which might very well launch several request per main directories involved.

Comment: Any ideas if it would be possible to mimic 'launch[ing] several request[s]' on the command line?

Comment: @Tim: without considering directly Emacs itself, I would try to wrap the `lsco` in a script which would list all directories, and for each one call an `lsco -nrec` (non recursive), to see if that process is quicker than one giant recursive `lsco`.

Comment: Worked through that. It is considerably faster, but still no where even close to the GUI. Oh well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not with the exact same behavior.  But if you use a dynamic view,

```
cleartool lspriv -co -s
```

is probably much faster than

```
cleartool lsco -r -cview
```

And if the former isn't what you want, maybe you can set up a filter script around it to fit your needs.

Comment: Please note that 'lspriv' doesn't list checked-out directory elements.