# ClearCase: Stop making baseline if there are checkouts

Tags: warnings, clearcase, cleartool, baseline

I'm using cleartool to make baselines in my stream, using

```
cleartool mkbl -full <baseline-name>
```

If I have files checked out in my view (in my case, always an oversight), I get the warning

```
cleartool: Warning: There are checkouts in view "<JXG-view-name>".
```

But as this is just a warning, `cleartool` continues with making the baseline.

What I need to do is *stop* immediately when given this warning.

How can I abort the command automatically when I get this warning?  I thought it would be a `cleartool` command-line option for `mkbl`, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no native way to look for checked out files on a [`cleartool mkbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) itself.
It will simply labelled any checked-in elements, leaving the current checked-out version untouched.

However, you could try and write a pre-op trigger on `mkbl` (a bit as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3536976)) in order to perform an `cleartool lsco -cview` and see if there are any files checked out.

```
cleartool mktrtype -element -all -preop mkbl -nuser ccadmin -exec "..."
```

You can [limit the `lsco` to a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576701/how-to-find-out-all-the-checked-out-files-in-a-branch/1577552#1577552) (the one named after the Stream) in order to [avoid any performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071650/cleartool-lsco-r-cvi-me-is-extremely-slow-compared-to-cleartool-lsco-grap/8072339#8072339).

Comment: Ugh.  This is *so* not what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @JXG why a trigger wouldn't be a good solution for your case?

Comment: Actually, it is, thanks.  I was just hoping for something simpler, ready out of the box.