# From a kdiff3 file comparison, can I generate a diff in unified diff format?

Tags: diff, kdiff3, unified-diff

I have a kdiff3 comparison in Windows, and I would like to save the comparison as a text file in unified diff format.

I realize this is kind of a strange question.  Usually, people already have the text diff in hand, and want to see it graphically in kdiff3.

I'm using an ... *[unusual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147055/how-do-i-roll-back-a-file-checked-in-to-clearcase)* ... version control [tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588781/clearcase-stop-making-baseline-if-there-are-checkouts) in Windows, and it can compare versions and display the comparison in kdiff3.  However, it is decidedly unfriendly in generating Unix-friendly output, at least for non-ClearCase-ninjas like me.

What I would really, truly, love is to get the output of the comparison in a unified diff format, so I can use tools like `patch` or similar.  I do not particularly love ClearCase, and I would be happy to leave it alone as much as possible.

Can kdiff3 take an existing comparison and export it to a unified diff format?

Comment: I would have upvoted this, but apparently I did so when running into the same issue 2 months ago.

Comment: Cleartool has a [diff](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm) command.  Check the -diff_format option for a standard Unix style output.

Comment: I keep re-googling this question, and keep ending up using [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to make a patch file (since you mention Windows, I thought adding WinMerge as a comment was fair game). His post's a little old, but [Joachim said it doesn't exist in KDiff3 back in Dec 2011](http://sourceforge.net/p/kdiff3/discussion/197500/thread/59c87108/), and I took that somewhat quick answer to mean that it's not likely to come later. YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

kdiff3 in Windows tends to come with the standard command-line diff utils as well -- look in your `C:\Program Files*\KDiff3\bin` folder; if diff.exe is there, you can use that (the standard `diff -u file1 file2`). (If it's not there, re-run the kdiff3 installer and select the "Utilities" option.)

If you're looking at some files in a running kdiff3 that was auto-launched from ClearCase, open a command prompt in the kdiff3 bin directory (or copy the contents of the bin directory into `C:\Windows` to make these commands work from anywhere) and do:

`diff -u "<copy-pasted path of file A>" "<copy-pasted path of file B>"`

where the paths for file A and file B come from your kdiff3 window (doesn't matter if they're temporary files; they'll exist as long as the kdiff3 window is open).

Answer (score -4):

Don't bother with kdiff3. The [command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm) you're looking for is

```
cleartool diff --diff-format
```

Answered by John here: [From a kdiff3 file comparison, can I generate a diff in unified diff format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826132/from-a-kdiff3-file-comparison-can-i-generate-a-diff-in-unified-diff-format#comment27112886_12826132)

Comment: This might help the OP but it doesn't answer the question.

Using KDiff3 on windows...